# Postman - json request string contains auto-added backslashes

Tags: json, postman, backslash

My json request has a timestamp value as below:

```
"startDate":"2023-03-15T00:00:00"
```

When I call an API with this request, I got an error

```
Can not deserialize value of type java.time.OffsetDateTime from String \"2023-03-15T00:00:00\": Text '2023-03-15T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 19\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@62d24954; line: 7, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.abc.request.OneRequest[\"startDate\"])
```

**What would be the root cause?**

Comment: The date format string is not valid. Look for the valid strings

Comment: @Serge you're right, the timezone is missing. The issue has been fixed. Please answer the question, then I will accept your answer, thanks!